# Mips datapath procedure for executing an AND instruction?

Tags: mips

Based on this figure, executing the AND instruction would cause these values to be assigned to the signals labeled in blue:

```
RegWrite = 1
ALUSrc = 0
ALU operation = 0000
MemRead = 0
MemWrite = 0
MemtoReg = 0
PCSrc =0
```

However, I am a little confused which inputs will be used in the Registers block? Can anyone describe the overall AND procedure in the MIPS datapath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from after the instruction is read from instruction memory, you need to know that `AND` is an r-type instruction and thus uses 3 registers. Which register is actually used is based off of the encoded instruction. (An R-Type has 3 5-bit fields, one for each reg.) `rs` and `rt` go to Read register 1 and 2, while `rd` goes to Write register. From there, Read data 1 and 2 (the bits of registers s and t) go to the ALU where a bitwise `AND` is performed on them. The result of that is written to the write register. I traced the path in your picture (omitting the PC incrementing part). I'm taking a class that uses that exact book this semester. If you look a little ahead, it goes deeper into what is going on. The explanation of the control (blue) lines helps a lot. The mux blocks are multiplexers, that is they allow alternating the output between two inputs. In this case, the ALUSrc mux will use Read data 2 because `AND` is an r-type. If it were i-type, it would switch to use the data coming from the sign extend, because that would be the immediate. The other mux is to allow either memory from data to be written to the write register or the result of an ALU operation. In this case, it will be the result of an ALU operation.[image]

Comment: hey thank you for the answer. what is the book called?

Comment: Computer Organization and Design by Patterson and Hennessy. We're using the 4th edition, but my professor has said multiple times he preferred the 3rd. Mainly because the 4th removed an appendix that contained information about logic gates and other electrical engineering type stuff.

Comment: Great answer!  Let's not ignore the PC --> IM and PC = PC + 4 part -- these are also part of the datapath (as are not the control paths).

Answer (score 0):

To imply answer your question about the register block, keep in mind that the inputs to the register block are the **addresses** of the registers your instruction will be using, the register block then either fetches the data in the registers who's addresses were given or write data at the end on this register.

However one note you have an inconsistency in your mux design MemtoReg and ALUSrc should have opposite values, so unless one of the 2 muxes is upside down (which is not advisable) then there is a mistake with your controller logic.

Comment: The book makes that mistake at least once (maybe a few times). They even switch the order from one diagram to another. Ie switch from 0 to 1 activating the top.